# jQuery doing an action when HTML Input uses Autofocus

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few pages that have long forms on them.  Some of these forms are pre-populated and if there is a pre-populated field at the top of the form, I use autofocus to automatically allow the user to start typing in that field.

in addition to these fields, I will occasionally have "notes" pop up next to the field to give more guidance as to what they are typing in.  These notes only come up when the user is focused on the input field.

Here is the code to show the field next to the input on focus:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
    var hasCont = $(this).parent().siblings('.cont-note').length;
    if(hasCont == 1){
        $(this).parent().siblings('.cont-note').fadeIn(400);    
    }
});
```

This, unfortunately does not work with html input's autofocus.  I want to avoid using jQuery to focus on a field, I would rather use html (for ease of modification)

My goal is: IF there is a note next to an input field that has autofocus, show the note.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the elements based on wether or not they have the autofocus property, and then trigger a focus event to get the focus event handler to trigger etc. but only one element can have focus, so maybe using first() would be a good idea ?

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
    var hasCont = $(this).parent().siblings('.cont-note').length;
    if(hasCont == 1){
        $(this).parent().siblings('.cont-note').fadeIn(400);    
    }
});

$('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('autofocus');
}).first().trigger('focus');
```

Comment: This is the most perfect answer I have ever received.  Thank you so much!  I will accept the answer soon, but I'm not allowed to accept within 10 minutes.

Comment: and thank you for showing me the .filter()  I have not heard of this before

Comment: I was trying to select fields with `$('*[autofocus="autofocus"]')`, which didn't work, but your method with `.filter()` was brilliant and worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the .attr() function?
You give your input field an extra attribute called noteID and on focus you use the .attr() function to get the ID. Now you can select without having to go hunting around the DOM.

```
$('.hasNote').focus(function() {
    var noteID = $(this).attr("noteID");
    $('#' + noteID).fadeIn(400);
};

<input type="text" class="hasNote" id="whatever" noteID="same as the note id" />
<note id="noteID">
```

Obviously I am just using the ID here, change `<note` to whatever element you need.

Comment: Do you think this would be compliant HTML?  Could this break older browsers?

Comment: @ntgCleaner This will work in IE7+ and equivalent versions of all major browsers.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Also, if you prefix the attribute with 'data-' then it is HTML5 compliant http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes